# Somatorio de valores do checkbox

Tags: javascript

tenho o seguinte script

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {

  $(".soma").bind("blur change check", function() {
  total = 0;

   $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() {
   total+=parseFloat($(this).val());
   });

   $(".soma").each(function() {
   if( $(this).attr('type')=='text' || $(this).is('select') ) {
   total+=parseFloat($(this).val());
   }
   });

   $("#input_resultado").val(total.toFixed(2));
   $("#resultado").html(total.toFixed(2));
  }
 });
```

Ele pega o valor do checkbox faz uma somatoria e salva dentro de um variavel.

Esse codigo está funcionando, mais agora parou.

Algem poderia me ajuda.

Comment: Muda o `}` que está sozinho no final para `});` para fechar devidamente o `$(".soma").bind(`

Comment: Sergio, fiz isso mais ele continua nao dando resultado na variavel